# Jasmine file input uploads an image, the image onload inside of FileReader is not fired in test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, dom-events

I'm new with Jasmine/Karma and I recently encountered a problem with input file. I want to test the width and height of the image I uploaded. If it doesn't fit the max or min values given, it will add class "ng-invalid-image-dimension" to input.
Now the code works but in test, the function image.onload is not triggered. I don't know why and it had me stuck for several days. Please help!

imageUpload.directive.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('components.imageUpload', [])
    .directive('imageUpload', function(defaultImages, imageDimensions) {
    return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        name: '@',
        maxWidth: '@?',
        minWidth: '@',
        maxHeight: '@?',
        minHeight: '@'
    },  
    require: '^form',
    template: '<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" ng-model="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files,name)">',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, form) {
        scope.maxWidth = scope.maxWidth || scope.minWidth;
        scope.maxHeight = scope.maxHeight || scope.minHeight;
        scope.form = form;
        scope.uploadFile = function(files, imgName) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.imgName = imgName;
                scope.file = files[0];
            });
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.readAsDataURL(scope.file);
            r.onload = function(file){ 
                console.log("filereader onload triggered");
                var validateW = false;
                var validateH = false;
                var image = new Image();

                image.src = file.target.result;

                image.onload = function() {
                    console.log("image onload triggered");
                    validateW = checkImageDimension(this.width, scope.minWidth, scope.maxWidth);
                    validateH = checkImageDimension(this.height, scope.minHeight, scope.maxHeight);
                    if(validateW && validateH) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {scope.form[scope.name].$setValidity("imageDimension", true);});
                    } else {
                        scope.$apply(function() { scope.form[scope.name].$setValidity("imageDimension", false);});
                    }
                };  
            };
      };
      function checkImageDimension(val, min, max) {
          return (val >= min) && (val <= max);
      }
  }
})
})();
```

imageUpload.directive.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="file" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="file" placeholder="{{name}}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files,name)">
</div>  
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <span class="help-inline" ng-show="form[name].$error.imageDimension">Image dimension is not valid !</span>
</div>
</div>
```

imageUpload_test.directive.js:

```
describe('components.imageUpload', function() {
var $compile, $rootScope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('components.imageUpload'));
beforeEach(module('js/components/imageUpload/imageUpload.directive.html'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

describe('image-upload directive', function() {
    var element, scope, input, files, inputScope;
    beforeEach(function() {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<form name="testForm" novalidate><image-upload name="testImage" default="false" type="png" min-width="150" max-width="300" min-height="57"></image-upload></form>');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        input = element.find('input');
        inputScope = angular.element(input).scope();
    });
    it('should have ng-invalid-image-dimension class when uploaded a wrong size file', function(done) {
        var mockFileHex = ["iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAA3CAYAAACo29JGAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA2hpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8iIHhtbG5zOnN0UmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VSZWYjIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtcE1NOk9yaWdpbmFsRG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDpEQjE3N0M0MDMxMjA2ODExODIyQUI1MDY3MDVEMjIwMCIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo0MDc2MTlGMDVGQjExMUU1QTIwMEFFNzQ2ODAyRUNEMSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo0MDc2MTlFRjVGQjExMUU1QTIwMEFFNzQ2ODAyRUNEMSIgeG1wOkNyZWF0b3JUb29sPSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ1M2IChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6REIxNzdDNDAzMTIwNjgxMTgyMkFCNTA2NzA1RDIyMDAiIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6REIxNzdDNDAzMTIwNjgxMTgyMkFCNTA2NzA1RDIyMDAiLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz4NQclSAAAFzElEQVR42tyaa2gcVRTH/zP7yuxm8zbJxmhJqaTGSukjRijaiG181lDFtKIWHygiluaLllahFdKW4ofkg4itqB8EsfRDURRsNEhFUtMYEqRNW1uNpYmG1M2zyT5md8Zzd8e8nH3c2dlskgOXOyQ7e+9vz7nnce8VYLKonfBQ9yC1DdQqqa2iVkwtOzQGS3iMnkSogoiQYMEoPfdT30H9MdtW9Jg5F8EkoArqdlHbQe3OWJ8jOETgYk3GioBgx1nqDxDojxmFI6ha6vZRq0vm84ngZotoh1dwoMlWh5YFhSOotdSxQWt53uOBm56gHaOiA68S5Mm0whGURN1harupWXgHMwI3rUkJ3QS6xbYFw0m/wwG2mrpz1BqNgKUqig/rlEkMyN/hMVPhCOwJ6rqorUEGRQ0hKzyBr+XTaDIFjsBeou4UNScWg6hk2jfxtvwtPkkJTgP7mMd8F0rCk3gxEaCYwBQ/wiKWCGAcExVigLFA/IvZppiKt4zn7y1uPE5B/5uEcJq7P5cO55EWuGhm4xdduHV+mNAzy8OZ9opGvKgaxPdx15yWeezGEhQWB+VWPB1Pcy2ZCNCmAQZwXBdOS4JrsYSFTDOPtNeop7l9WAaiBvDOHDitHqtL+YtlEcqkLbOmGUQh5Z/3s2er9rddRr8s0FOMydYKBC8UIfyPFHXNjjDslcPI2jgIZ10fRHdQPwiPSBj+ogqTvYWQx61QlGhssthVODw+5Ndfgat6wIj3fJe6BwRNc73xKmjdX2jMgZHmjfB3ehLUY2FkP/Ub3A2XEPaFI3FO8Vsx9H41xn/Nh6rGH8fp8aNsfzsseX6euBdw1CNL0PY8/uIFu7F3M0LXc5J+x1Yxhtw97Qhed6D/aA1kf/KlpE1SsOLoGVjyfUm/Y8nBOgb3HD1/xgPnPbgpocZ0E9kCH7wDKpQwv/lLpQHc/l5b8nDZ+FDUdqmSluCVfENgkTXmzTIExsQ36ICvpzT5dRdGDYOr5BnE/1N5xjzhWOtKjrWDcga3imcA+VpOxuACfzt5NJfH4Iq5nMlU5uKYEkg+M1QVWBlcNt8IQsbguPbqFAgib6JsLbuZMTZrTpDPOzMnxvOCY82NjMG5qrzccFyqkO7rhyCFFt4iySRz6y/zkKkMbohrEAJzPfLHgsNl3zFOWUcg+XmKCDG4q7wDuXdehKXIxz1B1SCYSOl9yRtdfJq2YJTBXeYezCWjYO/PlKAqC0LneeECV16pmWU/g+syMqCdFnf+Wx30E6lpNceS7X3I3nyNf41a0MHg2owOLG0aQOGBdghZobQ4kNKGq8h78qJBW8Yxw/XcbAn1uzF85F7If+bGj6uKipGpxOZldago29MF6e4hYz+MVs/9t4dyIqXgWj6BW1ra4N5xiX6x1Mw0565RrPyg1TBYtEDG2emERttDMcW/y7/nUYVeDbkvl0tzNkmF57VuSOsHU54DFaq1tq04M52tEeBpMzaJonsYIiZOrKZGlh4W4sKx/+Zu8JKr7yQTUFIem52l27ehaHr3S5MjpjkDmmTOs70obm6DbcV47O0Dp4Lb3uxCSWOHKWDRzamZU585eTZp7weYvDHLtvsmPq/CxMnKSBXONGe2tmattVHHNuTHglurxT3Tt9QD54sw1FSDiWEFZa+bs7b+t9bcaJh960HvCKsZmNmSNlP8fRLUQAiiUzb9u9ltB/ujWD+/Kpgv+6mdT0s9VuBLCxg7n2PXOPRKnrkfrAZzZ+ya0xSWgpDtiU7s1LufonsmToAsY3kmUqwvcrG4cIhi2pexilXEAPyKulcWOdintodmTnWShtMA2VWIlxejBiNgD0euksAQ3CzA7YtmDQqRrfJDicB0Q0HMYNyJKi3BNnwZINXbDJFbC8x5xFhj3Jqb52TuQfTcPLzQCmNxLHIdI0kwLs3pZDLL676lDiSDW143ZXUg2fHL8zDvjvNBVo+Z4HvMlRRupx8noG4z5/KvAAMAg2UEHy8DCrwAAAAASUVORK5CYII="];
        var blob = new Blob(mockFileHex, {type:'image/png'});
        blob.name = "logoTest";
        files = {0: blob, target: {result: {}}};
        inputScope.uploadFile(files, "logoTest");
        expect(input.hasClass('ng-invalid-image-dimension')).toEqual(true);
    });
    })
})
```

As I mentioned above, "image onload triggered" never displayed.